# can't change options of a select element in a drupal web form

Tags: select, drupal, drupal-webform

Im new to drupal. I had created web form with few elements and two select boxes. All went well. that was last week.

Now, I want to change the values, and strangely I can't see list of Values anywhere in the form component page. I can't even see how to create a new selectbox and give new options.
I think I kill some module responsible for this. Im not sure.

FCKEditor is installed, if that helps.

screenshot: http://twitpic.com/2sqytr

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the node, you should see a `Webform` tab, if you click that you should go to the overview of the webform form, where you can edit existing form fields and add new ones.

Comment: I tried that but I can't locate any textarea with option values written. check the new screenshot.

Comment: What version of the webforms module are you using?